# Troubles with appending values in ordered dictionary from a loop

Tags: similarity, ordereddictionary

I'm attempting to write a program which takes a number of input sequences (strings) of variable length and counts the number of identical characters at the same index in each string to find the strings with the highest number of matches. If strings are of differing length, I'd like to append 'N' characters to the end until they are the same length.

```
import random

def DNA(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice('CGTA') for i in range(length))

seq_lst = [DNA(20) for i in range(5)]
print(seq_lst)

from collections import OrderedDict

count_dict = OrderedDict()
count_dict['_0_to_1count'] = 0
count_dict['_0_to_2count'] = 0
count_dict['_0_to_3count'] = 0
count_dict['_0_to_4count'] = 0
count_dict['_1_to_2count'] = 0
count_dict['_1_to_3count'] = 0
count_dict['_1_to_4count'] = 0
count_dict['_2_to_1count'] = 0
count_dict['_2_to_3count'] = 0
count_dict['_2_to_4count'] = 0
count_dict['_3_to_1count'] = 0
count_dict['_3_to_2count'] = 0
count_dict['_3_to_4count'] = 0


indexa = 0
indexb = 1
indexc = 0
indexd = 0

for i in seq_lst[indexa]:
    if i == seq_lst[indexb][indexc]:
        count_dict[indexd][2]
        indexc += 1
    if indexc == len(seq_lst[indexb]):
        indexb += 1
        indexd += 1
    if indexb > len(seq_lst):
        indexa +=1
        indexb = indexa + 1
    if indexa > len(seq_lst):
        break



print(count_dict)
```

**Edit**
A new angle I'm working:

```
seqs = ['GTACGCCTTCTTCGGATTGTTAGCCCCTTTTGTTGGGTTACTGCT', 'CCGTGGTTGTTTGTTGAGCTGGGGCTTGTTGCGTGATGCAGCAT', 'TGGGAATTTTGGAATGGGGGAAACCCTGATCAGCCTCCCGCGTG', 'GGGTGTGTGAAGAAGGCCTTCGGGTTGTAAAGCACTTTCAGCGG', 'GATGAAGGCCTTCGGGTTGTAAAGTACTTTTGGCAGAGAAGAAA']

indexa = 0

for i in seqs: # iterates through each string in list seqs
    if len(i) < ((max(len(i) for i in seqs))): # Identifies any string which is 
                                                 shorter than the longest string
        seqs[indexa].append('N') # Appends all shorter strings with 'N' to make 
                                   the same length. (**DOESN'T WORK** How to 
                                   call the index of the current iteration?)
    indexa += 1 # Count for append

print(seqs)

largest_matches = []

seq_pos = 0 

    for i in seqs: # iterates through each string
        matches = {} # Creates dictionary to keep track of counts for each 
                       comparison
        for j in seqs[i]: # Iterates through each character in the current 
                            string

                for s in seqs[i+1:]: # Compares character at index j in the 
                                       current string i to *only* subsequent 
                                       strings, at the same index value
                    if j == seqs[s][j]: # Compares the current character (j) 
                                          in the current string (i) to the 
                                          corresponding character in subsequent 
                                          strings (s)(**NOT SURE IF THIS 
                                          WORKS**)
                        matches[seqs[i][j], seqs[s][j]] += 1 # Counts "matches" 
                                                               at each index
**NEED CODE HERE FOR SUMMING ALL MATCHES AT EACH INDEX FOR EACH PAIR. FOLLOWING CODE SHOULD WORK IF A DICTIONARY CALLED MATCH_SUMS IS CREATED PRIOR (I'M NOT SURE HOW TO DO THIS.)**                  
        for l, o in match_sums.items(): # iterates through summed match counts 
                                            for each pairing
            if o == max(o) # checks to see if current value, o (matches),  at 
                             key l (string pair) has the largest or tied for the 
                             largest number of matches
            largest_match.append(l, o)
    seq_pos += 1
    if seq_pos == (len(seqs)):
        break # ends loop at sequence 5, or last sequence, as all pairings have 
                then been evaluated. (4 to 5 being the last pairing here)
'''
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, matches in what way? Doesn't sound like you provided the whole problem, or your teacher doesn't understand the technical details behind the problem. 

Different ways I could see matches..

Comment: Matches meaning identical characters at the same index in different strings.

Comment: Alright I'll write something different and edit my answer once I'm back home tonight.

Comment: Sorry late response work hit me with the oof. Why do you want to add N characters to the end of the DNA sequence? It isn't required for comparing them, you can just find the max length of all the strings make character arrays of that size, and the characters will just be considered the default value if you don't fill whole array with the string.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand part of what you're asking, but I'll provide a great way to compare two strings, which then can be used to compare the dictionary you create with *n* permutations.

There is a concept in computer science and mathematics called the **Levenshtein Distance**, which is used to measure the difference between two sequences of characters.

It is a great base for literary analysis and having a computational way to compare strings, and you can use it to determine how many changes it will take to get from one string to a next through insertions, deletions, and substitutions.

Mathematically, this distance of strings *a* and *b* is measured by:
[image: levenshtein distance]

Some psuedo code for the [**Levenshtein Distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
function LevenshteinDistance(char s[1..m], char t[1..n]):
  // for all i and j, d[i,j] will hold the Levenshtein distance between
  // the first i characters of s and the first j characters of t
  // note that d has (m+1)*(n+1) values
  declare int d[0..m, 0..n]

  set each element in d to zero

  // source prefixes can be transformed into empty string by
  // dropping all characters
  for i from 1 to m:
      d[i, 0] := i

  // target prefixes can be reached from empty source prefix
  // by inserting every character
  for j from 1 to n:
      d[0, j] := j

  for j from 1 to n:
      for i from 1 to m:
          if s[i-1] = t[j-1]:
            substitutionCost := 0
          else:
            substitutionCost := 1
          d[i, j] := minimum(d[i-1, j] + 1,                   // deletion
                             d[i, j-1] + 1,                   // insertion
                             d[i-1, j-1] + substitutionCost)  // substitution

  return d[m, n]
```

Another similar method is the [**Damerau–Levenshtein distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance).

From my experience, this is what I'd recommend in order to find which ones are the closest match, since you can get the distance (of either formula) between two DNA sequences, and then pick the one that has the smallest distance of all comparisons. Since it sounds like a homework problem, I don't want to give the solution since you need to learn, but there's plenty of resources online and this should give a great start to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I could see how Levenshtein distance could be an ideal method, but for this I'd like to avoid it and just count matches using some more basic python 3 commands. Thank you!